# Simple C# output command prompt application

Tags: c#

I currently am working on a code which accepts a text file and then  displays the number of characters that begin with a specific letter. Right here, I have made some code and I am having trouble fixing the logic error which I am creating. If anyone can help, please help me understand what I am doing wrong here so I can immediate start improving! I am coding in c# and using visual studio as well. Here below is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This is loop constantly occurs
    while (true)
    {
        string UserInput;
        int count = 0;

        // here I ask for user input then convert to text file.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a text file into the console.");

        UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        char LastCharacter = UserInput[UserInput.Length - 1];

        // Two letters I am looking for at end of text file words.
        foreach (char item in UserInput)
        {
            if (item == 't')
            {
                count++;       
            }
            else if (item == 'e')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("There are {0}", + count + " words that end in t or e.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here is my output which I am getting in the command prompt.

```
Enter a text file into the console.
//Entered user text
that is the way

Result:
There are  2  words that end in t or e.
Press any key to continue...
```

notice, it is only counting the t's at the beginning of the word. I'm having difficulty changing that setting so it counts the "e" and "t" at the end of the word.

(Loop repeats)
Enter a text file into the console.

Comment: "_I have made some code and I am having trouble fixing the logic error which I am creating_" If you could help us helping you by explaining the error your observe... that would be helpful...

Comment: Please show an example of your input and what is expected as result from that input

Comment: What does **'Enter a text file into the console'** mean? It's ambiguous.

Comment: Also, what do you think `foreach (char item in UserInput)` is doing? Probably what you think it does is not what it really is doing...

Comment: If you struggle with understanding what your code is doing, there is a rather excellent tool at your fingertips which allows you to inspect and watch the state and values of your variables while your program is running. This tool is called Debugger. It is not that difficult to learn how to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger

Comment: You state you want to *"displays the number of characters that begin with a specific letter"*. Do you mean *words* instead of *characters*?

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Please see numbered comments to see where you had errors.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    while (true)
    {

        // This is loop constantly occurs.

        //variables;
        string UserInput;

        int count = 0;

        //Where I ask for user inout then convert to text file.
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a text file into the console.");

        UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        char LastCharacter = UserInput[UserInput.Length - 1];


        // 1) You need to extract the words in the user input - this assumes they are delimited by a space
        foreach (var word in UserInput.Split(' '))
        {
            // 2) You want to check the first character of each word 
            // 3) The StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase assumes you want to ignore case - if you DO want to consider case, remove the parm
            // 4) You can do the compare using the 'or' operator - no need for else if
            if (word.StartsWith("t", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || word.StartsWith("e", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                count++;
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("There are  {0}", +count + "  words that begin with t or e.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon. Thank you. Thank you helping me understand it more and see where I needed to fix my syntax and formulas. If i could give you 100 stars, i will.

Comment: The code isn't working actually. Whenever I make the output statement, it only says 1 character is found even when multiple characters are found.  The phrase: "I love that pork". This has the total value of characters ending in (t or e) to be 2. However, my code is displaying it as 1 count. This is a logic error which is happening.

Comment: @GrizzleShizzlePumkinPatch, well, look carefully at the code. Do you think `word.StartsWith` rhymes with "ends with"? ;-)

Comment: Please read *your* initial comment. "...then displays the number of characters that *begin* with a specific letter." No - I think *YOU* are not being clear about what you are asking.

Comment: @JonVote, true, but the code also states (and which you took over into your answer): `Console.WriteLine("There are  {0}", +count + "  words that end in t or e.");` So, should we rolling the dice?

Comment: The dude asked how to count letters *beginning* from a word. I copy/pasted his code and fixed it so it counts the number of letters *beginning* from a word.

Comment: Well, technically he never said anything about "words" until the string that includes "ends with". :)

Comment: OMG really? I'm assuming the person is not a native English speaker and: "I currently am working on a code which accepts a text file and then displays the number of characters that begin with a specific letter." means he wants to count the beginning character of each word.

Comment: Your first comment under your own answer is asking for an up-vote. Then, the 2nd of your comments is already full aggro-mode. Chill man, open the window, breathe, take a break.

Comment: Yeah - in response to "If I could give you 100 stars..." I'm not in aggro-mode. No windows here :( or I would take your advice.